# ListView onItemSelected Listener

Tags: java, android, listview, onitemselectedlistener

I wanted to show the image only at the selected row from listview. Here is the code:

```
private class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    public ListAdapter(Context context) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return attendeeList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.attendee_listview_row,
                    null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.txt_dName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtDisplayName);

            viewHolder.txt_dAddr = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtDisplayAddr);

            viewHolder.txt_dtelNo = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtDisplayTelNo);

            viewHolder.btn_scan = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnScan);
            viewHolder.registered_tag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivRegisteredTag);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.txt_dName.setText(attendeeList.get(position)
                .getAccountName().trim());

        viewHolder.txt_dAddr.setText(attendeeList.get(position)
                .getAttendeeAddr().trim());

        viewHolder.txt_dtelNo.setText("Tel no: "
                + attendeeList.get(position).getTelNo().trim());        

        viewHolder.btn_scan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                viewHolder.registered_tag.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

With these code, I am trying to show the registered_tag upon btn_scan onClick. However, the image is not really showing at the selected row. It shows at other row instead.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any ideas? I am really stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are getting last row image change when clicking on any row because `viewHolder` will contain last row view when `getView` called. Use `setTag` and `getTag` method of `viewHolder.btn_scan` view to save and get selected row view in onClick method:

```
viewHolder.btn_scan.setTag(viewHolder);
viewHolder.btn_scan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
               ViewHolder selectedViewHolder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();
               selectedViewHolder.registered_tag.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               ...
            }
        });
```

Comment: So I put these code after convertView.setTag(viewHolder);. And remove my button onClickListener?

Comment: @IWasSoLost: No, just use these code in place of setOnClickListener

Comment: I see but do you have any ideas how to delay the image showing for 10 seconds?

Comment: @IWasSoLost : yes sure you can delay image visibility using `Hanlder.postDelayed`

Comment: Nevermind I figured out by using a Handler to post delay it already. Thanks :)